# merge_request_event preventing downstream pipeline to trigger?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a very weird problem with gitlab pipeline.

I have the following constellation.

Upstream '.gitlab-ci.yml' -> ServiceA Repository

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      when: always

job1:
  stage: deploy
  trigger:
    project: 'Infrastructure'
    branch: 'master'
    strategy: depend
  rules:
    - when: manual

job3:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - |
      echo 'do something 1'

job4:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - |
      echo 'do something 4'
```

Downstream '.gitlab.yml' -> Infrastructure Repository

```
job2:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - |
      echo 'Preparing Infrastructure'
```

Now this works, as you can see only interesting part of the pipeline Upstream Pipeline uses '- when: manual', if any point in the time

Now if convert this the following (the reason for it I will have a library of pipelines and I will use those from several services).

Upstream ServiceA Pipeline becomes...

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      when: always

job1:
  stage: deploy
  trigger:
    include:
      - project: 'ci-library'
        file: '/jobs/prepare-environment.yml'
    strategy: depend
  rules:
    - when: manual
```

'/jobs/prepare-environment.yml' -> 'ci-library' Repository

```
include:
  - local: '/jobs/prepare-infrastructure.yml'
  - local: '/jobs/prepare-services.yml'
```

'/jobs/prepare-infrastructure.yml' -> 'ci-library' Repository

```
job5:
  stage: deploy
  trigger:
    project: 'Infrastructure'
    branch: 'master'
    strategy: depend
```

Downstream '.gitlab.yml' -> Infrastructure Repository

```
job2:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - |
      echo 'Preparing Infrastructure'
```

Now this is not working with message 'downstream pipeline can not be created, Pipeline will not run for the selected trigger. The rules configuration prevented any job from being added to the pipeline.' if I later on start the 'job1' while it is a manual...

If I remove the

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      when: always
```

this works also, so this has something to do with 'merge_request_event'.

My assumption the pipeline for ServiceA runs and later on I click the run for manual action merge request thinks, there is no diff in the merge request and it should not run...so how I can convince the Upstream pipeline to add the job?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, I'm just gonna leave the solution that worked for me if anyone is looking in this page.I had just to add the following workflow rule to the downstreams

ex : job1/.gitlab-ci.yml

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "parent_pipeline"
```